# How can I get content from InputStream based results in Play tests

Tags: java, playframework, akka, akka-stream, playframework-2.6

I am on Play 2.6, using Java

My controller returns:

```
public Result xml() {
    return Results.ok(new ByteArrayInputStream("<someXml />".getBytes()));
}
```

I want to parse the result in tests:

```
Result result = new MyController().xml();    
play.test.Helpers.contentAsString(result)
```

This throws

```
failed: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Tried to extract body from a non strict HTTP entity without a materializer, use the version of this method that accepts a materializer instead
```

How can I retrieve the content of results issued from input streams in tests?

Comment: Are you working with Scala or Java? And could you please post some more code, especially on the test side?

Comment: Post a minimum example of the test code where you see this error.

Comment: I use Java. After some more debugging I found out that it's not related to the MIME type. It comes from the result, built from an InputStream. The body of the result is then a HttpEntity.Chunked and not a HttpEntity.Strict, methods from the Helpers class doesn't handle that. I edited the inital question accordingly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the exception message states, since your result is a streamed entity, use the version of [`contentAsString`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/java/play/test/Helpers.html#contentAsString-play.mvc.Result-akka.stream.Materializer-) that takes a `Materializer`. Here's an example from [`HelpersTest.java`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.6.11/framework/src/play-test/src/test/java/play/test/HelpersTest.java#L124) in the Play repository that uses that method:

```
@Test
public void shouldExtractContentAsStringFromAResultUsingAMaterializer() throws Exception {
    ActorSystem actorSystem = ActorSystem.create("TestSystem");

    try {
        Materializer mat = ActorMaterializer.create(actorSystem);

        Result result = Results.ok("Test content");
        String contentAsString = Helpers.contentAsString(result, mat);
        assertThat(contentAsString, equalTo("Test content"));
    } finally {
        Future<Terminated> future = actorSystem.terminate();
        Await.result(future, Duration.create("5s"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Play 2.8 with akka 2.6, 'ActorMaterializer' has been deprecated. This is the way to get a 'Materializer'

`Materializer mat = Materializer.matFromSystem(actorSystem);`